# Игра "Black Jack" на Javascript

Tags: javascript

Я начинающий программист Javascript. Прохожу бесплатный видеокурс на сайте geekbrains.ru. У меня при написании игры "Black Jack" sublime text отображает предупреждение, мол, зачем заново объявлять переменные i и card во второй части кода, когда считаем тузы, если они уже объявлены? А в видеоуроке они заново объявлены.

[image: игра "Black Jack" на Javascript]

Вот мой код:

```
 [![<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset = "utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

// функция для получения числа случайным образом
    function getRandomInt(min,max){
   return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1))+min;    
}

// функция для получения карты случайным образом
function getCard(){
var cards = \["6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K","A"\];
return cards\[getRandomInt(0,card.length-1)\];
}

// функция для подсчёта суммы карт на руках
function getSum(hand){
var sum = 0;
// сначала считаем все карты,кроме тузов
for (var i=0;i<hand.length;i++){
var card = hand\[i\];
if(card!="A"){
    if (card =="J" || card == "Q" || card == "K"){
sum = sum +10;
   } else {
sum = sum + parseInt(card);

}

}   

}

// туз считается равной 1,если текущая сумма больше 10,иначе равной 11  
for( var i=0;i<hand.length;i++ ){
    var card = hand\[i\];
    if (card == "A"){
        if (sum>10){

    sum = sum + 1;
    } else {
    sum = sum +11;
}

}   

}   

return sum;
}

// функция для подсчёта текущего состояния очков дилера и игрока
function getstatus(){
    return "dealer: " + dealer.join('') + "iqrok: " + player.join("");
}

// описываем набор карт дилера и игрока
var dealer = \[getcard()\];
var player = \[getCard(),getCard()\];


// проверка на Блек Джек игрока
if (getSum(player)==21){
    alert("Black Jack!!!,Pozdravlaem!!");
    }
    else {
var answer = "";
do {

     answer = prompt(getstatus() + "Хотите ли вы играть дальше? 1 - да,иначе - нет");
// сдаём карту игроку
     if(answer == "1"){


     player.push(getcard());

// проверяем нет ли перебора или блек джека
     if(getSum(player)>21){
     alert("Perebor" + getstatus());
     break;
     }

     else if (getSum(player)==21){

    alert("Pozdravlaem,Black Jack!");
    break;
     }
    }
// игрок закончил брать карты
    else{


        // теперь карты берет дилер

        while(getsum(dealer)<17){
            dealer.push(getCard());
        }

            if (getSum(dealer)>21){

                alert("Perebor" + getstatus());
            } else if(getSum(dealer)==21){
                alert("Black Jack" + getstatus());
            } else if (getsum(player)==getsum(dealer)){
                alert("Nichya" + getstatus());
            }

            else if(getsum(dealer)>getsum(player)){

                alert("Viiqrish" + getstatus());
            } else{
                alert("Proiqrish" + getstatus());
            }

        }

     alert(getstatus());

     }while(answer==1);
    }

alert("Karti dealera: " + dealer.join('') + "Karti iqroka: " + player.join(''));
alert("Tekuchaya summa kart: " + getSum(player));

</script>
</body>
</html>][1]][1]
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему?

Comment: Попробуйте заменить все var на let

Comment: при замене var на let Sublime Text выдаёт warning: let доступен в ES:6(Esversion:6) или расширений Mozilla JS

Comment: ваш программа не верно считает.  если например передать [ 'A', 'K', 'A' ] Ваша программа выдаст 22 а не 12 =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для переменных, область видимости у которых должна быть в рамках одного {} стоит использовать `let` вместо `var`

Comment: при замене var на let Sublime Text показывает следующий warning: let доступен в ES:6 или расширений Mozilla JS

Comment: правильно, потому что let появилось в es6

Comment: а как теперь установить es6 в sublime text?

Comment: Его не нужно устанавливать, он просто предупреждает для того, чтобы Вы понимали поддержку броузеров.

Comment: но жёлтая точка слева не исчезает же,когда я пишу let вместо var

Comment: Видимо, Вам нужно установить расширение которое добавляет синтаксис ES6 в саблайм. https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Ecmascript%20Syntax - что-то типа, глубже не подскажу, пользуюсь phpstorm.

Comment: а как Вы поняли что в данном случае,в данной части кода нужно использовать let вместо var.? Я прочитал про let в интернете,ознакомился с ним, но причину использования его в данной части кода не понял.